# Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are Normal and independent random variables, $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are independent random variables, how do I prove that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are also independent?

What happens with the independence between $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ when $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2) $

Thank you

Comment: Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal, $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent if and only if $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_Y^2$.

Comment: You only need to prove their covariance is 0 since uncorrelation implies independence for normal distribution.

Comment: @Patrick: that is not true.  If $X$ has a standard normal distribution and $Y=X$ when $|X| \gt k \approx 1.538$ and $Y=-X$ when $|X|\le k$ then correlation is $0$ and $Y$  also has a standard normal distribution but they are not independent.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for pointing it out. They need to be jointly normal distributed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831387/321264

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**:

0. Independent Gussian random variables make a Gaussian random vector.
1. Affine transform $Y=A X + b$ of Gaussian random vector $X$ is Gaussian.
2. Distribution of Gaussian random vector is determined by its mean vector, and covariance matrix.
3. If components $X_i$ and $X_j$ of the Gaussian random vector are independent, then $\mathbb{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = 0$.

Combining facts given above, it follows that evaluation of $\mathbb{Cov}(X+Y,X-Y)$ will help establish the result needed.

Comment: No, you've got your "if" and "then" in the wrong order to get the conclusion you want.  You want to prove independence.  You need to show that IF the covariance is $0$ THEN they're independent, NOT that IF they're independent THEN the covariance is $0$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I agree. I was saying that since the mean vector and covariance matrix determine the distribution of a Gaussian vector, zero cross-covariance $\mathbb{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0$ implies independence of $X_i$ and $X_j$.

Comment: Hence one should add *0. Independent Gaussian random variables make Gaussian vectors.*

Comment: @did Thanks. Added.