# Prove that if X and Y are Normal and independent random variables, X+Y and X−Y are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that if X and Y are Normal and independent random variables, X+Y and X−Y are independent. Note that X and Y also have the same mean and standard deviation.

Note that this is a duplicate of [Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are Normal and independent random variables, $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206303/prove-that-if-x-and-y-are-normal-and-independent-random-variables-xy-and), however, there isn't a complete solution to the answer given and I do not understand exactly what the hints are suggesting.

My attempt was to check if $f_{x+y,x-y}(u,v) = f_{x+y}(u)f_{x-y}(v)$, however, this does not seem to be working out too nicely.

Comment: You left out an assumption.  $X$ and $Y$ need to have the same variance for this to be true.

Comment: Yes you are correct, in my specific case X and Y actually have the same mean and standard deviation.

Comment: WLOG you can assume the mean is $0$.  Then write out the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ and note that it has radial symmetry. $(X,Y) \to (X+Y,X-Y)/\sqrt{2}$ is a rotation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831387/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $U = X + Y, V = X - Y$. Then, $X = (U + V)/2, Y = (U - V)/2$. Find the Jacobian $J$ for the transformation.

Then, $f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X}(x=(u+v)/2)f_{Y}(y=(u-v)/2)|J|$.

You will find that $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ factors into a function of $u$ alone and a function of $v$ alone. Thus, by the Factorization thm, $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Comment: I came back to update, I was able to work this out with the hint you gave. Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 0):

For the general case that $X$ and $Y$ **have a bivaraite normal distribution and have the same variances**, it can be shown that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent (the means can be different and they can be dependent). It holds because of the following three facts:

**1**- $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are *uncorrelated*, i.e., their covariance is zero.

**2**- $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ again jointly follow a bivariate normal distribution.

**3**- When $(W,U)$ follows a bivariate normal  distribution, $W$ and $U$ are independent if and only if $W$ and $U$ are uncorrelated.