# Are the random variables $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ independent if $X, Y$ are distributed normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables such that $X,Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, show that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent using the moment generating function.

I know that the moment generating function of a sum of independent random variables is the product of the MGF.

So, I´m trying to solve that but i don´t know if my process is correct

$M_{X+Y}(t_1,t_2)=M_X(t_1)M_Y(t_2)=M^2_{N(\mu,\sigma^2)}(t)$
?

Comment: What you need to show is the MGF for the random vector $(X + Y, X - Y)$ can be factorized to the product of MGFs of $X + Y$ and $X - Y$.

Comment: Looks like question 81 in chapter 2 of the 11th edition of introduction to probability models by sheldon ross. Maybe this comment might help someone find this question via google.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/206303/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219780/321264

Answer (score 12):

Recall that for an $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ random variable, the moment generating function of it is 
$$M(t) = \exp\left(\mu t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2\right). \tag{1}$$

By condition, $X + Y \sim \mathcal{N}(2\mu, 2\sigma^2)$ and $X - Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2\sigma^2)$. Therefore by $(1)$, we have:
$$M_{X + Y}(t) = \exp\left(2\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2\right), \; M_{X - Y}(t) = \exp\left(\sigma^2 t^2\right).$$

On the other hand, as a bivariate random vector $(X + Y, X - Y)$, its MGF can be computed by definition as follows:
\begin{align}
& M_{(X + Y, X - Y)}(t_1, t_2) \\
= & E[\exp(t_1(X + Y) + t_2(X - Y))] \\
= & E\left\{\exp[(t_1 + t_2)X] \times \exp[(t_1 - t_2)Y]\right\} \\
= & E\left\{\exp[(t_1 + t_2)X] \right\}\times E\left\{\exp[(t_1 - t_2)Y]\right\} \quad \text{by independence of $X$ and $Y$.}\\
= & M_X(t_1 + t_2) M_Y(t_1 - t_2) \\
= & \exp\left(\mu(t_1 + t_2) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t_1 + t_2)^2\right)\exp\left(\mu(t_1 - t_2) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t_1 - t_2)^2\right) \\
= & \exp\left(2\mu t_1 + \sigma^2 t_1^2\right)\exp\left(\sigma^2 t_2^2\right) \\
= & M_{X + Y}(t_1) M_{X - Y}(t_2).
\end{align}

Hence $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ are independent.

Comment: I have one question, when you say: $E\left\{\exp[(t_1 + t_2)X] \right\}\times E\left\{\exp[(t_1 - t_2)Y]\right\} \quad \text{by independence of $X$ and $Y$.}\\$ it is a property?, I only know that E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) but I didn´t know that property.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly this property, where you treat $(t_1 + t_2)X$ and $(t_1 - t_2)Y$ are independent random variables. Notice that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are all constants.

Comment: so, when I have 2 independent random variables X,Y $E[g(aX)h(bY)]=E[g(aX)]\cdot E[h(bY)]$ is always true?

Comment: Yes, you made a good guess. Of course, rigorous, $g$ and $h$ needs to be measurable, which is usually guaranteed.

Comment: it´s an interesant result that i didn´t know, can you suggest me a site where find the proof to this property?

Comment: I have already found a pdf with this proof, thank you, your answer was very useful!

Comment: Good for you. You are welcome.

Answer (score 10):

An answer using moment generating functions has already been given, but please also consider the following simpler approach.
Note that two jointly normal random variables are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated. Since $X,Y$ are independent normals, the pair $(X,Y)$ is normal. Any linear transformation of a normal is also a normal, so $(X+Y, X-Y)$ is normal, i.e. $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are jointly normal. Then $E[(X+Y)(X-Y)] = E[X^2 - Y^2] = \sigma^2 - \sigma^2 = 0 = (2 \mu) \cdot 0 = E[X+Y]E[X-Y]$. Thus $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case that $X$ and $Y$ **have a bivaraite normal distribution and have the same variances**, it can be shown that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent. It follows from the three facts:

**1**- $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are *uncorrelated*, i.e., their covariance is zero.

**2**- $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ also jointly follow a bivariate normal distribution.

**3**- For $(W,U)$ with a normal bivariate distribution, $W$ and $U$ are independent if and only if $W$ and $U$ are uncorrelated.