# Are the projections along orthogonal direction of multivariate normal distribution with diagonal covariance matrix independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

I'm taking a probability class and my prof used the following theorem IIRC.

Let $g\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is diagonal( I don't know if this condition is necessary) and $\langle u,v\rangle=0$, then $\langle g,u\rangle$ and $\langle g,v\rangle$ are independent.

Is this correct? If so, how to prove this?
I believe the following is a special case of the theorem: [Are the random variables $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ independent if $X, Y$ are distributed normal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625714/are-the-random-variables-x-y-and-x-y-independent-if-x-y-are-distribut) 
I tried to use the same technique to prove the theorem but got stuck.

Comment: If $\color{blue}{ u^T \Sigma v = 0}$, then you can show that $u^T g$ and $v^T g$ are independent. It won't generally hold if just $u^T v = 0$. Hint for showing this: write $z := (u^Tg, v^Tg)^T$ in the form $Ag$ for some matrix $A$, and use that the covariance matrix of $Ag$ is $A\Sigma A^T$. Also recall facts about linear transformations of normal random vectors and when such a vector has independent components based on its covariance matrix).

Comment: So actually $\Sigma$ doesn't need to be diagonal?

Comment: Correct! All that matters is that $u^T \Sigma v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Minus One-Twelfth's comment:

The pair $(g^\top u, g^\top v)$ is jointly normal. (Why?)

Thus independence is equivalent to $\text{Cov}(g^\top u, g^\top v) = 0$.
The covariance is
$$\begin{align}\text{Cov}(g^\top u, g^\top v)
&= E[(g^\top u - E[g^\top u])(g^\top v - E[g^\top v])]
\\
&= E[((g - \mu)^\top u)((g - \mu)^\top v)]
\\
&= E[u^\top (g - \mu)(g-\mu)^\top v]
\\
&= u^\top E[(g-\mu)(g-\mu)^\top] v
\\
&= u^\top \Sigma v.
\end{align}$$

---

If $\Sigma$ is a multiple of the identity matrix and if $\mu = 0$, then independence is equivalent to $u^\top v = 0$. However, in general you have to use the above expression $u^\top \Sigma v$.

Comment: Why is it jointly normal? Is this a property of the multivariate Gaussian variable? I know that $g^Tu$ and $g^Tv$ are both normal.

Comment: @YihanZhou [One way to check that it is jointly normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions) is to check that any linear combination $a(g^\top u) + b (g^\top v)$ is [univariate] normal. Indeed, any such linear combination is itself a linear combination of the components of $g$.

Comment: Why $E[(u^Tg)(g^Tv)]=u^T\Sigma v$? Sorry I'm not stat major and don't know much about multivariate Gaussian.

Comment: @YihanZhou See my edit; I made a mistake earlier.