# If $X,Y$ are i.i.d. standard Normal r.v.s, why is $\operatorname{Var}(\max(X,Y)) = \operatorname{Var}(\min(X,Y))$?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, variance

Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. standard Normal r.v.s. Let $M = \max(X,Y), L = \min(X,Y)$. Why is $\operatorname{Var}(M) = \operatorname{Var}(L)$? The answer key simply states: "By the symmetry of the Normal distribution ..." which isn't sufficient for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This result does not require normal distribution. It is true for any i.i.d. symmetric random variables $X$ and $Y$.

$-M=\min \{-X,-Y\}$ which has  the same distribution as $\min \{X,Y\}=L$ since the joint distribution of $(-X,-Y)$ is same as that of $(X,Y)$ (by independence and the the fact that $X,-X$ have the same distribution; $Y,-Y$ have the same distribution).

Thus, $Var (M)=Var (-M)=Var L$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\max(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2}(X + Y + |X - Y|), \min(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2}(X + Y - |X - Y|)$.  In addition, when $X, Y \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ [are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625714/are-the-random-variables-x-y-and-x-y-independent-if-x-y-are-distribut/1625748#1625748), implying that $X + Y$ and $|X - Y|$ are independent. Therefore:
\begin{align}
 & \operatorname{Var}(\max(X, Y)) \\
=& \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}(X + Y + |X - Y|) \\
=& \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}(X + Y) + \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}(|X - Y|) \\
=& \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Var}(X + Y - |X - Y|) \\
=& \operatorname{Var}(\min(X, Y)).
\end{align}